# Making a script read a text file and update when a new line is added

Tags: batch-file, text

here is what i have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:loop
set vara = 0
set varb = 0
if NOT %vara% == %varb% (
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type Chat.txt') do ( 
    set /a %vara%=%vara%+1
    set "Var=%%x"
    ECHO !Var!
)
set %varb=%vara%
)
goto loop
pause
```

but when it opens it crashes instantly, any help?
edit:
now i got

```
@ECHO OFF
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
title NOOOOPPPEEEE
set varb=5
:loop
set vara=0
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type Chat.txt') do ( 
    set /a vara=vara+1
echo %vara%
)
echo %vara%
echo %varb%
pause
if NOT %vara% == %varb% (
cls
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('type Chat.txt') do ( 
    set %varb%=%vara%
    set "Var=%%x"
    ECHO !Var!  
)
echo %varb%
)
goto loop
pause
```

but it won't change varb to vara (which in this case is 3 with the file i am using)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `vara` nor `varb` is set up at the time the `if` is encountered.

With a standard `set` command, spaces on either side of the `=` are significant, so your command sets up "vara<kbd>space</kbd>" to be "<kbd>space</kbd>0"

You could use `set /a` for a numeric-assignment, where spaces are ignored.

Since neither variable is set up, the `if` command becomes

```
if == (
```

so `cmd` produces an error message about the problem.

Since you are apparently running by clicking a shortcut, `cmd` then closes and you see nothing.

It is normally assumed that if youare working at developing `cmd` scripts, then you are running from the command prompt. You can do this by finding "command prompt" (under "all programs>Accessories" if my memory serves me), and `SEND`ingg that to the desktop. If you click that new shortcut, you'll get a black screen wherein development is far simpler.

BTW,

```
set %varb=%vara%
```

and its variants used in your script sets a variable named "(the **contents** of `varb`)" to ... - it does not set "varb"

**AND** any `%var%` is resolved at the time that the *outermost* code-block is parsed, so if `vara`=0 at the time the `if` is encountered, then

```
set /a %vara%=%vara%+1
```

would attempt to set a variable "0" to a value of (0+1) **every** time within the inner loop

See endless SO items about "delayedexpansion" for more.